# Web Browser in a fullscreen Direct3D application

Tags: browser, direct3d

I need to have a working web browser in a fullscreen Direct3D application.  For example, Valve's Source-based games (sort of) do it in the MotD window when you join a server.  Any tips on where to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second Life uses ubrowser (http://ubrowser.com/) to embed a browser over a 3D world. As the source code is available for the Second Life client (http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/Get_source_and_compile) it would be a good place to see how they have done it.

Note however, they are using OpenGL, not Direct3D... but there is nothing specific in ubrowser itself to OpenGL.