# c++ D3D chromium embed

Tags: c++, direct3d, chromium-embedded

I tried to create an D3D application which includes the Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF) for web content. I read through various documentations and wikis (both, official and private) but none of them defined how to apply a CefBrowser into D3D. As far as I recognized I need to define a parent window which holds the CEF.
But to which parent class/window should I apply for rendering through D3D ?
If I overlooked something please let me know, and if don't I would be very glad about any related information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct in that CEF expects to be hosted in a Windowed application.  Consider creating a windowed app, in which you can create both CEF Browser windows and D3D surfaces in their own windows (you can play with window ordering, styles, and compositing if you want to make it appear like the browser is "embedded" in the D3D app.)

Comment: There is no way to render the CEF through Direct3D ? I wanted to use it as a GUI for a D3D and OpenGL game, it wswould be much more complex to use an MFC window.

Comment: @Xurdrise What's a MFC window? Use a Win32 window. `RegisterClass` + `CreateWindow` *(with a parent)* type of window. Why use MFC?

Comment: Well, you could certainly use the offscreen rendering feature of CEF to generate pages and place the results in your game.  Here's a similar SO query with a result to how they did this in the "Second Life" client: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202567/web-browser-in-a-fullscreen-direct3d-application

Comment: Regarding prior comment: Note that you'd need to add a lot more "proxy" code in your D3D app to go with the offscreen-to-texture approach to handle input, etc. so I'd still recommend the windowed approach, at least initially.  CodeAngry is correct - you can used standard Win32 programming, WTL, wxWindows, etc. - no need to pull in MFC for simple windows.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replys ! @CodeAngry: sorry for the mfc mistake, i was tired. I also thought about that and still think it's a good deal though I would rather like to use the offscreen render method suggested by holtavolt. If I could only find a good documentation - the official left me with a huge amount of answers. But for the moment Im glad to walk on the right line, thank you guys !